# How to test if element is not clickable in react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have an element with an `onClick` handler which may be disabled by adding `pointer-events: none` to parent (parent disables children click).
Now I want to test that my child is not clickable, how can I do this?
Using `userEvent.click` throws error:

```
Error: Unable to perform pointer interaction as the element has `pointer-events: none`:
```

But this is exactly what I am trying to test...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `pointerEventsCheck` option of `userEvent.click`, which allows you to control how often the pointer events check is performed.

For example:

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent, {
  PointerEventsCheckLevel,
} from "@testing-library/user-event";

test("child is not clickable when parent has pointer-events: none", () => {
  render(
    <div style={{ pointerEvents: "none" }}>
      <button onClick={() => console.log("clicked")}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
  const button = screen.getByRole("button", { name: /click me/i });

  userEvent.click(button, {
    pointerEventsCheck: PointerEventsCheckLevel.Never,
  });

  expect(console.log).not.toHaveBeenCalledWith("clicked");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use `expect().toThrow()` as documented [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tothrowerror).

Depending on your test setup, you could also pass your `onClick` a mocked function and assert that it is never called.

```
test('onClick is not called', () => {
    const mockFn = jest.fn();
    render(
        <Foo onClick={mockFn} />
    );

    // Add logic to prevent click and fire the event.

    expect(mockFn).not.toBeCalled();
});
```

Comment: This would work but would test implementation and not behavior.